# How to shoot good night photos with Nikon S8000?

Tags: point-and-shoot, low-light, night, noise, blur

Some time ago, I bought a Nikon Coolpix S8000, with big satisfaction for daylight shoots, but in using it I realized that my night shoots were more frequent than I expected.

I tried to use it by night, ending with some disappointment, like blurry/noisy photos, caused probably by my inexperience.

I'd like to shoot good photos, possibly without using a tripod, in situations like concerts or city by night.

Can you give me some advice for the settings of the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unfortunately fairly limited as to what you can achieve with a point and shoot camera in tricky conditions like city night shots. To avoid blur you can increase the ISO right up to the camera's maximum of 3200, but you will get quite a bit of noise in your photos.

A tripod is more or less essential for night shooting even when using a DSLR. Obviously this is probably not practical for concerts, but it certainly shouldn't be a problem for cityscapes; you can get some decent, compact tripods these days that collapse into quite a small, portable package. The other option is a monopod, which is more portable but offers less stability.

Comment: Yes, the other problem of shooting by night is the big noise in auto mode without flash (if i'm able to shoot a photo keeping the camera firm). Perhaps, generally i can't shoot without a support. And i'm a little disappointed that my girlfriend's Coolpix S6000 can do better night photos without effort.